# Can I gain access to telephony settings through the contentresolver or elsewhere outside an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, adt, android-contentresolver

As part of a test utility on android I am gaining access to the telephony setting in my activity as follows:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().(Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers"), null, null, null, null);
```

Is it possible to access the settings outside an activity through the content resolver or through another manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AndroidTestCase and ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 both provide methods to get Context

AndroidTestCase:

```
getContext();
```

ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

```
getInstrumentation().getContext();
```

This Context provides access to the `getContentResolver()` but permissions to change are adopted from the application under test.